# Attach to tessera node failing

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, private-key, quorum

Im installed quorum with tessera but when i need to attach to any node using command $ ./attach.sh 1 show error "Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix qdata/dd1/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory"

Any one can help me .... thanks

Answer (score 1):

are you sure tessera is running ? are you sure the ipc file is at the location specified 'qdata/dd1/geth.ipc' ? how are you running the network ? are you using Quorum wizard ?

Comment: No ... not found ipc file in qdata/dd1/geth.ipc ... yes i used quorum wizard when create the quorum network

Comment: and the terminal show this sentence "Tessera is taking a long time to start.  Look at the Tessera logs in qdata/logs/ for help diagnosing the problem."

Comment: this basically means tessera did not start correctly. Make sure you have the right dependencies and you are following the instructions outlined here https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-wizard